# NSCompoundPredicate is giving me an error that states it can't find an overload for 'init'. This was working prior to latest XCode 6.1 update

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, nspredicate

**This is the piece of code causing error.**

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "status == %@", false )
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "published == nil || published == false" )
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [p1, p2]) as NSPredicate // <-- error line

activities = array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
tableView.reloadData()
```

I've looked at questions with similar errors but none can help me solve my issue.

Would appreciate some insight here.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works:

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "status == %@", false )
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "published == nil || published == false" )
if (nil != p1 &&
    nil != p2) {
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [p1!, p2!])
}
```

the problem is, since NSPredicate(...) can return nil, so your p1 and p2 variable's type is *NSPredicate?*